# Multidimensional array in function prototype

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array

I have a code like this:

```
class oBT{
    public: void clean(int**);
            void write(int**);
            bool check(int**);
            void backtrack(int**,int);
};

void oBT::clean(int R[8][8])
{ for(int i=1; i<=8; i++) for(int j=1; j<=8; j++) R[i][j]=0; }

void oBT::write(int R[8])
{
    for(int i=1; i<=8; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=8; j++)
            std::cout<<R[i]<<' ';
        std::cout<<'\n';
    }
    std::cout<<'\n';
}

bool oBT::check(int R[8], int i=1)
{
    for(int j=1; j<=8; j++)
    {
        for(int k=1; k<=8; k++)
        {
            if(R[i]==R[j]) return false;
            if(R[j]==R[j]) return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}

void oBT::backtrack(int R[8], int i=1)
{
    for(int j=1; j<=8; j++)
        for(int k=1; k<=8; k++)
        {
            R[j]=1;
            if(check(R))
                if(i<8) backtrack(R,i+1);
                else { write(R); clean(R); }
        }
}
```

and when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
C:\OJI\Eight Queen Puzzle\Class.h|8|error: prototype for 'void oBT::clean(int (*)[8])' does not match any in class 'oBT'|
C:\OJI\Eight Queen Puzzle\Class.h|2|error: candidate is: void oBT::clean(int**)|
C:\OJI\Eight Queen Puzzle\Class.h|11|error: prototype for 'void oBT::write(int*)' does not match any in class 'oBT'|
C:\OJI\Eight Queen Puzzle\Class.h|3|error: candidate is: void oBT::write(int**)|
C:\OJI\Eight Queen Puzzle\Class.h|22|error: prototype for 'bool oBT::check(int*, int)' does not match any in class 'oBT'|
C:\OJI\Eight Queen Puzzle\Class.h|4|error: candidate is: bool oBT::check(int**)|
C:\OJI\Eight Queen Puzzle\Class.h|36|error: prototype for 'void oBT::backtrack(int*, int)' does not match any in class 'oBT'|
C:\OJI\Eight Queen Puzzle\Class.h|5|error: candidate is: void oBT::backtrack(int**, int)|

||=== Build finished: 8 errors, x warnings ===|
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays. If you want to pass in multidimensional arrays, either use double pointers and dynamic memory allocation (i. e. `new`), or declare your functions to accept an array of arrays, like

```
void clean(int parm[8][8]);
```

etc.

Also, your `check` function has a 'typo', you omitted the 'size' argument from the prototype; instead of

```
bool check(int **);
```

it should be

```
bool check(int R[8][8], int i);
```

Comment: @UrecheVlad You're welcome. I'd suggest you read a paper on C pointers and arrays. You can also accept my answer if it helped, thanks.

Comment: I know my way around pointers and arrays, but I'm new to classes and function prototypes. I'm going to read into it further. Again, thanks a lot for the help.